# Single Big Table vs Multiple not so big tables on the same schema

Tags: database

Should we create a separate table for each pair of friends to store their chat messages OR should we create a single table storing the chat messages for all pairs (with appropriate keys to retrieve messages corresponding to each pair)?

- a chat between a pair of friends can be very large
- the single table will become very large over time as its stores ALL conversations for all pair of friends
- the multiple table option would have smaller tables because they correspond to a conversation between a single pair of friends but the number of these small tables would be large, also this solution would require another table to find out in which table the conversation corresponding to a given pair is stored.

Our question is 'which of the above options would be better and WHY considering issues like Response Time, Modifiability, Availability, etc.?'

How will the answer change if we consider distributed database setting?

Comment: Your 2nd option. "Create single table storing chat messages for all pairs (with appropriate keys to retrieve messages corresponding to each pair". You do not want to have thousands of tables..... One table is always easier to manage, because what if you want to add an attribute to the table, you would have to update all thousands of tables rather than one. Maintainability and reusability would be efficient in this case. And if you have good indexing you should be fine on response times.

Comment: How would the time complexity of alter table differ in the two cases? For example, if we want to add an attribute to the schema, then which one would be faster and why?

Comment: Doesn't Alter Table only allowed one table per query? Imagine you have millions of tables.. You are going to have to write 100000's of queries, compared to just one. I don't know time complexity algorithm, but I think the 100000's of tables would be O(n) because you have to update all n # of tables. The one table would just be O(1), because you are just updating one table.